# How do I use pdfplumber to find the number of pages?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Tried the following code

```
with pdfplumber.open("C:\Trial\Sample.pdf") as pdf:
#Total number of pages
    totalpages = pdf.pages
    for i in enumerate(totalpages):
        pageobj = totalpages[i]
        print(pageobj.extract_text())
    #loop end
#big loop end
```

I am getting the following error
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
with pdfplumber.open("C:\Trial\Sample.pdf") as pdf:
#Total number of pages
    totalpages = len(pdf.pages)
    for i in range(0 ,totalpages):
        pageobj = pdf.pages[i]
        print(pageobj.extract_text())
    #loop end
#big loop end
```